# What satellites can I receive Images from with a radio?

Tags: artificial-satellite, amateur-radio

Are there any satellites that I can receive image data streams with an SDR and antenna?
I already know about NOAA 15, 18, 19 and METEOR - M 2. Are there any other radio satellites that I can access and what are their frequencies?
I don't care if they face Earth or not.

Comment: This is a good and interesting question! People point home dishes at satellites and receive raw signals all the time, and in fact this exactly how Canadian amateur astronomer Scott Tilley discovered the long-assumed-dead IMAGE satellite while hunting for Zuma! See [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/24677/12102). However, decoding the data stream is harder than just noticing a carrier, thus, your question.

Comment: @uhoh - Check out [PrimeLuce Lab](https://www.primalucelab.com/radioastronomy/receivers/) for equipment at less than astronomical prices.

Comment: @Rob the 14-bit ADC and 1024 spectrometer channels sounds great for *radio astronomy* or SETI, but I'm not sure how that could be used to receive encoded image data from satellites.

Comment: Sort of like a Modem, you would receive an [eye pattern](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eye_pattern) guess what waveform encoding (not encryption) was used, demodulate the signal, and then attempt to figure out the manner in which the data was packaged, and once you've separated headers from data determine if it is encrypted. Some space agencies explain the type of transmission format they are using and how to apply the ECC, others (military satellites, even GPS) do not give all the details. **IF** you were not targeting a specific satellite you'd want a Software Defined Radio.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a post on how to receive from geostationary orbit (GEO) weather satellites like GOES:
https://www.rtl-sdr.com/setting-up-a-goes-weather-satellite-antenna-system/

You may also want to check this:
https://www.wmo-sat.info/oscar/satellitefrequencies
It lists satellite frequencies and their related services.
As far as I know, APT, AHRPT and LRPT should be images transmissions.