# Is it allowed to interact with research satelites / rovers using the radio?

Tags: artificial-satellite, rovers, law, amateur-radio, software-defined-radio

Let's say I have a SDR (software defined radio) like the [HackRF One](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HackRF_One) at home, access to a huge amplifier circuit and a giant antenna (at my university).

Is there a law that prohibits receiving / streaming video or measurement data from NASAs research satellites or rovers?

And what about sending? Would sending commands to initiate streaming video etc to a research satellite or a rover (like [perseverance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perseverance_(rover))) be a crime? Just asking out of curiosity ^^

Comment: You are probably getting better results at Law.SE, since this is about the law and is only tangentially related to space exploration.

Comment: The U.S. Department of Defense has officially invited you (and everyone else) to [go ahead and try to hack one of their satellites](https://www.hackasat.com) four days from now. (That's August 7-9 2020 for those reading this comment after the fact.)

Comment: I'm sure such actions (at least trying to control spacecraft or rovers) would be, at least, covered by existing laws governing hacking, which is what this would be.

Comment: somewhat related: [How did NASA prevent third parties from spoofing Apollo communications?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/27835/12102) and [What satellites can I receive Images from with a radio?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/28161/12102)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Receiving data from NASA spacecraft has happened several times, and seems to be fine. The problem is transmitting to said spacecraft where you can run in to legality issues.

Comment: At least in the US, the only "illegal" reception I can recall is the old analog cell/remote handset frequencies near 980MHz. The fact that they are still 'blocked' on commercial amateur broadband receivers is a little puzzling, to say the least.

Comment: For just some examples of those "several times" see answers to [Hijacked space data, notable instances of recovering images or other goodies from someone else's space mission?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/33359/12102) and [this](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/33346/12102) and [this](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/24140/12102)

Answer (score 1):

Radio spectrum licensing prohibits sending transmissions on the same frequency and location as where licences are granted to protect licence holders from interference.  So sending commands is not permitted, except as mentioned where there are invitations to attempt to hack to help the operator identify vulnerabilities.  One can always listen and in fact many satellite operators award "certificates" to amateurs who manage to collect and document transmissions from their satellites when first launch.  This can sometimes help the satellite operator verify correct operation of their spacecraft.  If you receive and decode a transmission, consider sending it to the spacecraft project office for verification and they may have the time to validate it for you.  If you'd like to get into the habit of regularly talking to satellites, consider joining a group like AMSAT which operates several earth orbiting satellites for the express purpose of letting members use the platforms to store and forward messages to other amateurs. Good luck!